# SQL UPDATE REPLACE WHERE BETWEEN

Tags: sql, wordpress, replace, where-clause, between

I'm trying to do an SQL clause that replaces a URL within a field if another field has a date from a value.

Something like:

```
UPDATE ThPjS_wp_posts
SET 'post_content' = REPLACE(post_content,'http://meudominio.com.br/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/','http://meudominio.com.br/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/')
WHERE 'post_date' BETWEEN
'2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-31 23:59:00'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: do you get any errors? what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok
check the result first before doing an update.

```
SELECT * from ThPjS_wp_posts 
from post_content 
WHERE post_date BETWEEN
'2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-31 23:59:00'
AND post_content LIKE 'http://meudominio.com.br/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/%'
```

do you get any result?

Comment: ups. you need to use % instead of * in the like condition

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
UPDATE ThPjS_wp_posts
SET post_content = CASE 
        WHEN post_content = 'http://meudominio.com.br/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/' THEN 'http://meudominio.com.br/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/'
        ELSE post_content --leaves the same value
    END
WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-31 23:59:00'
```

Pay attention on your `'post_content'` and `'post_date'` it's `without quote or with backticks`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, all you need to do is remove the quotes from around your field names, the rest looks pretty much OK.

```
UPDATE ThPjS_wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'http://meudominio.com.br/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/','http://meudominio.com.br/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/')
WHERE post_date BETWEEN
'2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-31 23:59:00'
```